# What are C's advantages over OOP languages, other than performance?

Tags: java, c++, object-oriented, python, c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When to use C over C++, and C++ over C?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/113295/when-to-use-c-over-c-and-c-over-c)

C still has its own importance in the programming world! And one reason for it is its performance. But, I have some questions.

- Is there anything that is special to C that other languages missing?
- What are its importance today, other than performance issues?
- What are the advantages of C over OOP languages like C++, Java, Python, etc.,?
- Is there anything other that gives a plus point to C?

Comment: almost every piece of hardware has a C compiler.

Comment: One of the main advantages is the lack of the OOP features, and therefore, a lesser chance for someone misusing them.

Comment: Another important thing: with C you won't have all that stupid libstdc++ problems and won't have to think about the ABI incompatibility issues.

Comment: @SK-logic:  Of course, if I were looking for a language that's hard to misuse, it wouldn't be C.  C++ has ways to deal with most of the most misuseable things about C (smart pointers, the string class, RAII) in addition to things like RTTI and operator overloading and templates and exceptions, which are easy to horribly misuse.

Comment: @David Thornley, that's exactly a list of things, an excessive use of which is often a much worse misuse than petty C pointer crimes. That's the reason why Torvalds did not want to use C++ - to scare away those prone to such a misuse: http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/57643/focus=57918

Answer (score 13):

I can name two: *simplicity* and *portability*.

C is much simpler than C++, which is the closest thing to C among the OO languages.  Just compare the K&R book to Stroustrup's "The C++ Programming Language".  Don't get me wrong, I love C++.  But it is a very complicated language, with an enormous number of language features, which take a long time to master.  C, by comparison, is very simple with only a few constructs.  And I am not talking about libraries here, just the bare language features themselves.  The same is true if you compare C with Java, C#, or any other OO language.  IMHO, the only language simpler than C is Scheme, a functional language.

The second reason is that there is a C compiler for everything.  Every processor and every operating system.  And I am not just talking about Windows vs. Linux.  There are hundreds of embedded platforms, processors, and DSPs.  You would be extremely lucky to have a C++ compiler for one of those, let alone a JVM.  But you would definitely expect to have a C compiler.

Comment: And of course one of the main reasons that there's a C compiler for everything, is that C compiler's are relatively easy as C is so much simpler...